# Можно ли имитировать подключение пользователя в Cron-задаче?

Tags: cron, servlet, spring-mvc, потоки-данных, java

Имеется сервлет, написанный с использованием Spring. Метод запускается по времени как CRON (тоже использует Spring Scheduler). Можно ли в этом методе создать как бы сессию с конкретным пользователем, чтобы создался поток с контекстом настроенным на этого пользователя с доступом к базе данных, а потом чтобы Cron-задача работала в этом контексте? Ну, как будто пользователь подключился и это для него все создалось.

Comment: Да, именно так. Я пробовала запускать, но похоже, она не создает свой контекст. Сейчас еще раз попробую и напишу точнее.

Comment: Ну да, пользовательский контекст отсутствует, и поэтому все вываливается при попытках к нему обратиться.

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю, что в данном случае "пользовательский контекст".

Comment: Какие данные конкретно из контекста нужны? Если имеется ввиду контекст Spring Security, который хранит текущего пользователя, то его руками можно засетать.

Comment: Да, именно это и нужно. А как его руками, он же из запроса берется?

Comment: Обычно контекст сетается с помощью

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);

где token может быть типа `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` - сущность с `username`, `password` и `authorities`, а `authorities` в свою очередь коллекция, которая реализует интерфейс `GrantedAuthority`. Если это действительно `Spring Security`, то где-то в проекте должен быть провайдер или сервис, который осуществляет аутентификацию. Метод `authenticate` в нём можно ручками вызвать откуда нужно.

Comment: У меня, похоже, через `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` метод `preHandle` это делается. Вот только не вижу, откуда он вызывается. Вроде нету нигде вызова.

Comment: Нет, это я, похоже, ерунду написала. Пытаюсь разобраться. SecurityContextHolder нету. SecurityUtils используется для логина. Но там непонятно, как засунуть туда пользователя. Лучше всего, наверно, HandlerInterceptorAdapter использовать, но туда надо запрос послать. Что это вообще за процесс, с крон. Он также в отдельном потоке идет? Есть там отдельный контекст и отдельная сессия? Ну в смысле, будет там также все защищено, как при обычной сессии, если я попытаюсь там слать запросы?

Comment: SecurityUtils это самописное что-то или из какой-то библиотеки? Что за процесс с кроном - вам виднее, всё что угодно может быть. Если у вас для секьюрити используется сторонний фреймворк, то я вряд ли смогу дать ответ на последний вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Передайте правильное имя-пароль пользователя для подключения к базе. Это уже решит 90% задачи. 
Если Вы используете какой-то специфический клиент, который завязан на пользовательское окружение, поищите в его настройках возможность передать это самое окружение. 
Если же он такой бедный и написан криво, то обычно помогает прописание переменной окружения PATH с правильными путями. Также крон позволяет задать имя пользователя, от которого запускается клиент.

Пример крон файла:

```
PATH=/home/pupkin/.program_config:$PATH

# m h dom mon dow user  command
 17 *  *   *   *  pupkin   cd / && ./super_proga
```

В некоторых случаях окружение настроено в .bash_rc. В этом случае достаточно просто его подгрузить при запуске задачи. Где-то так:

```
17 *  *   *   *  pupkin   source /home/pupkin/.bash_rc && cd / && ./super_proga
```

Comment: Ox, неправильно сформулировала. Речь о сервлете идет. В нем есть кусок, который запускается как CRON. Сервлет написан с использованием Spring, и там все завязано на пользовательский контекст.

Comment: как крон или с под крона?

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: В чем отличие?

Comment: из под крона - это из под крона - то есть, добавляется запись в crontab файл.

Как крон - это симуляция крона какими-то левыми утилитами/пакетами.

Если честно, то я не понимаю, как Вы собрались запускать сервлет.

Comment: В спринге есть Scheduler, который запусткает задачи, как крон-задачи по времени или с интервалом. Но как для такой задачи создать пользовательское окружение, этого я не нашла.

Comment: То есть, это никакой не крон, а жавовское подобие.

Вы пробовали запускать Вашу задачу в нем? если нет, то пробуйте, если да, то напишите, что именно не так происходит.